# PHP if statement read from txt and enables checked button

Tags: php, html, button

I have an on-off button in PHP and a txt file. When inside the txt file the value is true I want the button to be disabled (echo unchecked) and when the value inside the txt is false I want the button to be enabled (echo checked)
I try the following code but it always stays unchecked. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
$wifi2g=file_get_contents("wifi2g.txt");
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" <?php if ($wifi2g = 'true') {echo "unchecked"; } else  { echo "checked";}  ?> >
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparison.

Comment: It should be `if ($wifi2g == 'true')`.

Comment: also: why are you using a text file for this, instead of just another php file that you can `include`

Comment: if ($wifi2g == 'true') {echo "unchecked"; } else  { echo "checked";}  tried this way it stays always checked now

Comment: its a string inside a .txt file.

Comment: add `var_dump($wifi2g);` to make sure the variable is what you think it is

Comment: i get string(6) "true "

Comment: you have some spaces, "true" is only 4 charterers long

Comment: is that the only line of text that is in that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have the one line of text in that file (true) which appears to contain spaces as per your `var_dump()` result in comments *"i get string(6) "true " – La Erti B"*, you can use `trim()`.

```
<?php
$wifi2g=file_get_contents("wifi2g.txt");
$wifi2g = trim($wifi2g);
?>
```

You can use that or remove the spaces in the file, should it contain spaces.

However, another possible scenario would be that you may have a line break underneath it, which it would account for the extra 2 characters.

Should that be the case for either, `trim()` will still work.

Plus, as already stated. Your use of `if ($wifi2g = 'true')` is an assignment rather than a comparison.

`if ($wifi2g == 'true')`

---

*Writing to a file, another possible scenario.*

We don't know how that file gets written to in the first place. One possible reason for this would be that a `"\n"` may have been used during that time.

The `"\n"` is a line feed character.

Should it be the case, it either needs to be removed or as I already stated to use `trim()`.

- Both will produce `string(6) "true "` if the file either contains 2 trailing spaces, or no spaces but with a line feed under the line of text.
- **These are conclusive results.**

Answer (score 0):

A common error that's likely gotten us all at some point. You need to use 2 equals, because `if ($var='true'){`  will always be true, eg; assign var a value of true, and if successful (always) then...

Also, you don't need "unchecked" since if "checked" isn't in the tag, it won't be checked, so you don't need the else...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox"
   id="myonoffswitch" <?php if ($wifi2g == 'true') {echo "checked";} ?> >
```

Comment: you should read the comment thread before answering